# BeginFlush seems to work synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.5, httpresponse

I'm trying to use HttpResponse BeginFlush and EndFlush methods in order to make the flush async, which means my worker thread won't being used while flushing to the stream.

However it seems that the BeginFlush methods run in synchronous way always.
I dig in Microsoft reference code and didn't find the reason for this behavior.
This is Microsoft implementation: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,f121c649c992c407

I checked the SupportsAsyncFlush flag and I'm getting true , so my environment actually supports the AsyncFlush.

Any idea?

This is a code snippet for trying to do the async flush, but I'm not getting to the "Different Threads" line - it is always the same thread that runs this code.

```
        Context.Response.Write("Some message");
        Context.Response.BeginFlush(
            res =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var previousThreadId = (int)res.AsyncState;
                    var thread2Id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                    if (previousThreadId != thread2Id)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Different Threads");
                    }

                    Context.Response.EndFlush(res);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            },
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you are seeing may be related to SycnhronizationContext used by ASP.NET. Depending on .NET version and whether your code executes under ASP.NET page or something else, the behavior may change. Generally, it is normal for the SynchronizationContext to execute the callback on the same thread which started the async operation. You can find more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

In any case, you can check whether the callback is synchronous or not by checking weather the next line of your code (after BeginFlush) executes before the callback. That will indicate that the callback is indeed asynchronous.

Comment: Eventually I succeed to see the "Different Threads" line in my logs. I ran a very load test and it did the trick. Anyhow you are right about your suggestion with the next line checking...

Answer (score 3):

The code is *asynchronous*, but it's not *multithreaded*.  You're defining a callback; a method that will be run at some indeterminate point in the future when the flush finishes.  That doesn't necessarily mean that it'll run on another thread.

There are also many implementations of abstract functionality in .NET where the behavior is defined as asynchronous, but the implementation is synchronous because that particular implementation expects to run so quickly as to not warrant asynchrony.  This is true for a fair bit of .NET's file IO.  If the writer you're using expects to be able to flush the buffer very quickly, it may not bother doing it asynchronously.

Comment: Yes I thought that this might be the reason, but I did some heavy stress tests and none result with different threads... Any idea how can I simulate the long flushing? I think I'll try again with very large messages and the stress tests that I did. But I was afraid that I'm missing something due to the following comment from Microsoft: "If the underlying HttpWorkerRequest supports asynchronous flush and this method is called from an asynchronous module event or asynchronous handler, then the send will be performed asynchronously"

Comment: @TomerPeled `If the underlying HttpWorkerRequest supports asynchronous flush` That may not be the case for you.

Comment: I was afraid of the following specific line: "and this method is called from an asynchronous module event or asynchronous handler". I'm just calling it from some worker thread...

Comment: **If the underlying HttpWorkerRequest supports asynchronous flush** - I'm getting true when checking SupportsAsyncFlush - so my platform indeed support the async flush...